# Which type of pokemon Ash dosen't have?

Tags: pokemon

Ash has caught many types of Pokemon, but he does not have some types like the ghost type.

What types of Pokemon has Ash not caught yet?

Comment: Related, but asked backward: [How many pokemon did Ash catch?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35656/how-many-pokemon-did-ash-catch)

Comment: I am asking about types ex:- pikachu-electric type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of writing, Ash has owned 15 of the 18 types through by either catching or trading

The only types Ash does not own are

- Psychic
- <strike>Ghost</strike>

  > In the Sword and Shield series, Ash caught a Gengar in the episode "Ash Has Been Cursed.."
- Fairy.

[Source](https://reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/b1v2zc/updated_the_list_of_ashs_pokemon_by_type_the_only/)

Comment: However Ash does have Psychic and Fairy pokemon. Ash technically owns Mr Mime and can use it whenever he want. Mr Mime is a Psychic as well as Fairy Pokemon. So technocally shouldn't Psychic and Fairy be striked off as well?

Comment: @JitendraSingh I apologize for the delay in getting back to you. In all my research, it never mentioned Mr. Mime. I also re-watched the episode for clarification (S1E64), and it is ambiguous on whether Ash actually caught the Mr. Mime himself. In an episode of Pokemon Journeys (which aired in English after my answer), Ash does use Mr. Mime in battle. So it *was* caught at one point, but it's subjective on who caught it (Ash or his mom)